# How to fix "There is a problem parsing the package" when sideloading WhatsApp?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, side-loading

I downloaded the apk from [here](https://www.whatsapp.com/android/) with  WhatsApp version 2.17.106 (size 34601974 bytes).
There, it says: "Android OS 2.3.3 or above". I can extract the APK's contents without errors, so the file is not broken.

My old smartphone model is GT-S6102, a Samsung Galaxy Duos, running Android 2.3.6.

I have enabled "Install from unknown sources" and "USB debugging".  I have let Lookout scan it before installing.

When trying to install that APK using the file manager, I get this message:

> There is a problem parsing the package

I am also unable to install it from Google Play Store. From Google Play, it says "Package file is invalid".

**Update:** version 2.17.350 does **not** work again.

Comment: https://android-fix.com/android-errors/34-parse-error.html

Comment: @RahulGopi followed all things there to no avail

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/164153/cannot-use-whatsapp-in-gingerbread-anymore

Comment: @woliveirajr yes, duplicate in a way, but answers there did not solve my problem. In fact, a few weeks later, a new version of watsapp was working again! I guess, both this and that questions should be put in a suspended state (if there was one) until the problem happens again, if ever. And if it is not still happening to other ppl right now...

Answer (score 1):

File from https://www.whatsapp.com/android/  version 2.17.251 has minSdkVersion="15"  which means that it supports android 4.0 and later.
Declaration "Android OS 2.3.3 or above" is on the same place.

Ask support?

Comment: I think this is an answer, if confusingly worded -- the salient point being that the text is wrong and the min SDK version indicates why there's a problem.

Comment: I just re-downloaded it and cant find the sdk required version stored at what file? it opens with zip like app in ubuntu

Comment: I use https://github.com/google/android-classyshark/releases